# what is the best link for rss?

Tags: rss

Whether there is a standard for location of rss in website?
like this :

```
http://MyWebSite.com/rss.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard URL—any browser that supports RSS is going to do so by looking at the “alternate” link you specify in your page's header. For this page, for instance, it's

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question 'what is the best link for rss?'" href="/feeds/question/5004140"/>
```

The “href” attribute is arbitrary. Point it wherever you like.

Comment: ok Noah, but i mean was that is there any standard for crawler?

Comment: Nope. They'll look at the exact same thing as a browser would.

Answer (score 1):

If there is, I certainly have never come across it - and I have a whole slew of blogs in my RSS reader. Better to use a `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="" />` in your `<head>`.